# .net standard doesn't resolve child assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard, .net-standard-1.4

I create a .net standard 1.4 Library project from vs 2017 template.
Now I add a class to this  calles Foo.

Then I create a second .net standard 1.4 project (calles Consumer) and reference the first one as Project Reference.

Now I can't refrence types from the first library. I can reproduce it with new created projects see here: https://github.com/Gentlehag/NetStandardBugSample[image]

Same is true when using outside of visual studio

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

Here diagnostic build log
https://github.com/Gentlehag/NetStandardBugSample/blob/master/diagnostiglog.txt

Any advice whats going wrong or what to test?

Comment: found bug sorry for wrong post

Comment: it would be nice if you could post what was wrong so anyone else who runs into a similar issue can see your fix.

Comment: I had the same issue, restart of the Visual Studio fixed it.